# Confused about Match Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a thousand of rows of logs in `Column D`. I'm trying to find this reference no. `103370349075` using `Match Function` .
That log is in row 4225.

Here is my formula: 
`=MATCH("*103370349075*",D:D,0)`

It gives me error. But when I try to add the reference number in other nearer row, I get the result. Why is that?

Comment: Is the value in your cell a Number, or Number Formatted as Text?  This will be looking for a Text String that contains `"103370349075"`, but will *not* find the Number `103370349075`

Comment: Nice one @Chronocidal ! Type it as an answer with `TEXT(A1,"0")` and your done.

Comment: All the Log details are compressed in one column. So the value is in text string and also that is why I use wildcard

Comment: I found what's causing the problem. The Length of the text is >255 characters and can't handle above the limit.

Comment: @remoel You might want to Answer your own question and Accept it, so that this shows up as Solved to people glancing through :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are looking for a numeric you need the following

```
=MATCH(103370349075,D:D,0)
```

You need the " marks for text not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my problem is that the target cell has a length >255 characters and the `Match Function` is ignoring/skipping it. And that's why I am getting an error.